# Windows 10 - SATA Hard drive keeps disappearing

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sata

I have only recently upgraded my machine to Windows 10. This was a clean build with Windows 10 Pro, not an upgrade from 7 or 8.

My C drive is a 500 GB SSD. My D drive is a brand new 3 TB standard drive. The D drive keeps disappearing. It stays online for a while, but always disappears after a period of time (sorry, I don't yet know what that period is). When I go to MMC/Disk Management, and 'rescan disks', it immediately comes back online every time. I don't have to do anything. Just the act of 'rescan' makes the drive come back.

I am running SQL Server Developer on this machine. The databases are all on D. When it disappears, SQL server goes haywire, and fills my event log with errors. This really rules out 'going to sleep' or something like that.

I know all about the power settings for putting HDD to sleep, but that is set to 0. I did a full scan for virus/malware with Avast, Spybot, Malwarebytes, and Kapersky (all were either fresh installs, or uninstall and reinstall to be sure no corruption). None of them found a thing.

This is a machine that sits in a corner and used for backups only. It is behind 2 routers, plus windows firewall. There is not someone sitting on this machine using it for the internet. So the possibility of a virus is near 0, since this machine is virtually unused by users.

Anyone have any ideas? I tried running WD Lifegaurd on it. The ' Quick Test' tells me the drive is fine. I can't run the extended test, because it goes offline before the extended test can finish.

I do not use any special tools, such as stacker, encryption, bitlocker, or anything like that.  Just standard windows.  I've swapped power supply cable, SATA cable, and SATA port.  No change.  This is internal, not external.

Comment: Did the 3TB drive stay online when you were using your previous version of Windows?  If the drive is a recent addition and never worked right, are you sure your PSU is powerful enough to handle the existing hardware PLUS the 3TB drive?

Comment: It's worth checking the BIOS power-related settings, but it might be a PSU, or worse, a motherboard problem. Are you able to try to connect another HDD (maybe smaller than your current one) instead of this one?

Comment: The 3TB is brand new.  When I upgraded the machine, I tossed the old C and D drive, and put on a brand new C ssd, and D 3TB.

I have a spare PSU.  I will swap that out and try.

Comment: Well, it's now been 4 days on the spare power supply, and not one failure.  So it would appear that something in the power supply was faulting, and bringing the drive offline.  Good call!  I should have thought of that!!